# "Her" in a sentence

Tags: canadian-english

I have a question about the use of "her" in English.

Here is a conversation:

> Q. Any luck finishing your part? A. Working on her right now.

Here, does *her* refer to *part* A of the question? Is it like conversational language? Can *her* refer to anything else?

Comment: What's with the *Canadian English* tag? :) Did you read or hear this conversation? Did you make up this dialogue? Could you provide more context, please?

Comment: It is not an altogether unusual form of conversational English. Ships are always referred to as 'she'. People will apply the female pronouns to other things such as a car, and in this case even a work project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an altogether unusual form of conversational English. Ships are always referred to as 'she'. People will apply the female pronouns to other things such as a car, and in this case even a work project.